# How to plot a function after Integration in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to evaluate the Integral below and visualize it using sympy.

```
from sympy.abc import x,y,z
import sympy as S

def f(x,y,z):
    return (1)/(S.sqrt(x**2+z**2-2*z*x*S.cos(y)))

I1 = S.integrate(f(x,y,z),(y,0,2*S.pi),(x,0,z))
S.plot(I1)
```

The code outputs a blank graph with `TypeError: can't convert expression to float`

Is there a way to plot the function `I1` or evaluate it at a point?

Comment: The integral cannot be computed symbolically so you'll want to use a numeric integration routine: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html